# function pointer as template argument

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I have the following class template in "concurrent_sorted_list.h":

```
template <typename T, int (* Compare)(T,T)>
class ConcurrentSortedList{
 ....
}
```

in my main.cpp:

```
int (*intCompare)(int, int) = [](int a, int b) -> int {
  if (a < b)
    return -1;
  else if (a == b)
  return 0;
  return 1;
};

ConcurrentSortedList<int, decltype(intCompare)> c;
c.Add(5);
c.Add(6);
assert(c.Size() == 2);
```

But I get the following compiler error:
`expected a constant of type ‘int (*)(T, T)’, got ‘int (*)(int, int)’`

if I change `decltype(intCompare)` to `intCompare`, then I get the following compiler error:
`the value of ‘intCompare’ is not usable in a constant expression, ‘intCompare’ was not declared ‘constexpr’,  ‘intCompare’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘int (*)(int, int)’, it must be the address of a function with external linkage`

Comment: The template want to get a function pointer *value* argument, but you are passing it a *type*.

Comment: You cant use `decltype(intCompare)` because the template expects a value (and youre giving it a *type*). And using simply `intCompare` doesnt work because it's not a constant expression (another requirement for templates). I suggest you rethink your approach to this. This way will not work.

Comment: A function pointer template parameter must be *the address of a function with external linkage*. Any old function pointer value won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got way too many tricks in your code.  You just need:

```
int intCompare(int a, int b)
{
    if (a < b)
        return -1;
    if (a == b)
        return 0;
    return 1;
};
```

And then, as others have said:

```
ConcurrentSortedList<int, intCompare> c;
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7U2eBdH9yQ2msSJh)

`auto intCompare = [](int a, int b) -> int { ...` also works, FWIW.